# PHP Perl-derivative regex question

Tags: php, regex

In regular expressions we can escape special characters like: `/\. - dot/`

And what if I want to "escape" a substring: `/Some **esc.{2}aped** phrase/` (to match this pattern `"Some esc.{2}aped phrase"`) ? Is there any such character sequences (to replace `**`)?

PHP example. I have pattern

```
$pattern = "/Some unknown text {$here}: (\\d+)/";
```

with UTF8 string `$here`. And want to test UTF8 string `$input` with `$here` substituted "as is" (ignore special characters in `$here`):

```
preg_match( $pattern, $input, $matches );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you want to embed an unknown string into a reqular expression.

You can use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for this:

```
$unknown = "Some. Text";
$regex = '/Some unknown text '.preg_quote($unknown, '/').': (\d+)/u';
```

Also, for UTF-8 encoded regular expressions, you might want to use the `u` modifier to recognize UTF-8 character sequences.